# Bug in JQuery Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got jquery slider. Sometimes the slider's height is less than normal height.
I calculate #slider's height with Jquery because slider is responsive.

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
        <ul id="sliderres">
            <li><img class="slires" src="slider/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="slires" src="slider/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="slires" src="slider/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            <li><img class="slires" src="slider/4.jpg" alt=""></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px auto;
    width:1024px;
    position:relative
}
#slider #sliderres li{
    font-size:20px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center
}
#slider #sliderres li img{
    width:100%
}
```

JQUERY:

```
var sliuzun = $('#sliderres li:first-child').height(),
    time=0;
    $('#slider').height(sliuzun);
    $('#buton li:first').addClass('buton');
    $('#buton li').click(function(){
        var butind = $(this).index();
        $('#slider #sliderres li:eq('+butind+')').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#buton li').removeClass('buton');
        $(this).addClass('buton');
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        sliuzun = $('#sliderres li:first-child').height()
        $('#slider').height(sliuzun);
    });
    $.Slider = function(t){
        $('#slider #sliderres li').hide();
        if(time < t - 1){
            time++;
            $('#slider #sliderres li:eq('+time+')').fadeIn('fast');
        }else{
            $('#slider #sliderres li:first').fadeIn('fast');
            time = 0;
        }
    }
    setInterval('$.Slider('+$('#slider #sliderres li').length+')',2500);
```

Comment: `less than normal height` isn't much of a problem description. What does that mean? What is `normal` . Please update question with a proper explanation

Comment: what are you ting to achieve? do you want the images which are "less than normal height" get stretched to match the others? If so, try this CSS `#slider #sliderres li img{ width:100%; height:100%; }`

Comment: Please provide a live example, and perhaps a screenshot of the issue as you see it. Here's a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/prrstn/bpgyku1f/ 

I cannot create it since I don't have your images or their dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I upload 16:9 images. 9/16 = 0,5625. Width * 0.5625 solved problem.
And sorry for my bad English. I am Turk and I am at the 7. Grade